# When transcoding DVD contents, should I keep the 29.97 framerate?

Tags: video, dvd, handbrake, transcode, framerate

I'm using handbrake to transcode (the main stream of) a DVD into a x265+AAC file, using the [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) application.

The source material has a frame rate of 29.97 fps.

My question: When transcoding, should I keep the frame rate, or change it to something more, well, integral? If so, which frame rate should I prefer?

Note: My interest is maximizing retained quality, and secondarily making playback less taxing. I'm not considering reducing the framerate for a size reduction.

Comment: https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/1.3.0/technical/frame-rates.html

Comment: Decreasing bitrate will make file size smaller, with some experimentation you can get the best of both worlds. This is preferred to changing framerate/

Comment: @Moab: 1. That link doesn't answer my question. 2. I know decreasing the bit rate makes the file smaller. That's not what I asked; I don't want to decrease the framerate to reduce size.

Comment: All I can suggest is to experiment with different framerates and see how it affects playback of the transcoded dvd video.

Comment: You are overthinking this. If you are using x265 just keep it at whatever the source material framerate is. Doing anything else has no real benefit and might only cause headaches.

Answer (score 0):

I recently was looking for something similar, although I also wanted to reduce the filesize in addition to the goal of making playback easier. I found [this](https://github.com/donmelton/other_video_transcoding) very nice tool on GitHub which has the goal of creating transcoded versions of DVD and BluRay rips which are easy to play back on all kind of devices, and in addition reduce the file size by a few hundred mb almost without any loss in quality as the raw data from a DVD you buy is almost uncompressed, so there are possibilities to compress it down a bit without losing quality.

The tool is very well documented by the author and in addition there are already written instructions by other users e.g. for a docker installation. It is based on ffmpeg and handbrake, so if you already know handbrake you will find some of it's features there as well.

In conclusion: of cause you can keep the framerate but to the human eye there is no big difference as long as the quality of the frames is high enough, so instead going for a constant bitrate is easier for many video playback devices.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the 29.97 frame rate. It's an NTSC standard, but playable on every modern computer, phone or tablet or flat panel.

Start with the HandBrake preset Matroska/H.265 MKV 480p30.

Switch to the Video tab.Note that it says Framerate FPS = 30 with peak framerate. This is good. I would append :deblock=-1 to the Advanced Options for a slightly sharper picture.

Now choose the Audio tab. 2 ch @ 160k is OK for a stereo output, but many dvds have a 448k 5.1ch AC3 source. If you don't want this to pass through then choose an AAC  bitrate 448k and mixdown 5.1ch. If you just want stereo, then AAC 256k mixdown stereo (or DPL II) is very good.

Test your settings using Preview / Live preview 1 minute. When satisfied, make sure to save your custom preset (Presets/Add Preset)

Comment: I don't live in North America though...

Comment: If the target display is a computer, tablet, phone, or practically any modern flat panel, smart or not, it should still play just fine. If not, adjust the Peak FPS to 25 for PAL/SECAM